# Process Flow as a CMS user, 3 / 2 Tier?

Tags: content-management-system, environment

What is the recommended process flow for Development regarding development and as a CMS user?

A three tier architecture seems secure: 1)Quality Assurance 2)Production 3)Live

However would a 2 Tier: Production into Live straight away be okay to use, What are peoples thoughts on this? Is the three tier a general practice?

Thank You, Aisling

Comment: Sorry, I flagged this question for being way to vague, opinion-based and also not really related to programming.